# How do I debug with Xdebug in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: 8, debugging

When I try to debug Drupal 8 (8.6.11) using Xdebug in VS Code (I'm on Win 10 but I doubt it is relevant in this case) I get the following error:

> Exception has occurred. Dotenv\Exception\InvalidPathException: Unable
>   to read the environment file at /app/.env.

The problem is either with VS Code or with Drupal as someone has reported exact same behaviour on High Sierra and they were using Drupal 8.6.10:
https://github.com/lando/lando/issues/1501

I did not find anything in drupal docs about the neccessity of creating a .env file to use Xdebug, so I suspect a bug eihter in Drupal 8 or VS Code.

Has someone encountered similar behaviour?
Should I file a bug report on Drupal site?

Comment: It sounds like there is a DotEnv package enabled that is expecting to find a .env file?

Comment: @Kevin, could you be more specific? I'm new to Drupal and don't know what you are reffering to.

Answer (score 2):

`InvalidPathException` is an exception related to the [`vlucas/phpdotenv`](https://packagist.org/packages/vlucas/phpdotenv) composer package so this issue isn't related to the [Lando](https://github.com/lando/lando) & [VS Code](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode) codebases; it's an issue with your Drupal code base.

You can confirm `phpdotenv` is a Drupal dependency by looking at your `composer.json` file and looking at the `require` section.

The issue is the package dependency isn't finding the `/app/.env` file in your Lando environment. Confirm that the `.env` exists in your Lando project root (the same dir as your `.lando.yml` file).

Comment: I should have added that I'm using Acquia Dev Desktop and the site is working fine. It is only when I'm trying to use Xdebug in VS Code that the problem is occuring. Why doesn't the bug fire off when using Acquia's setup? As I said earlier I'm new to Drupal, but shouldn't the .env file be loaded only when it exists as I concluded from reading the contents of the dotenv.init.yml file?

Comment: I can only speculate since no one can debug your own environment except you. Try following the stack trace for the exception that originally caused that error.

Comment: It turns out that I made a mistake - to anyone who may experience similar strange exceptions: check if in your VS Code when in debug mode under BREAKPOINTS label you don't have the box next to 'Everything' checked - if yes then uncheck it and you should be fine :-)